# Creating a layer from a selection, when I try to symbolize or label the layer, it brings back all the non-selected features

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, symbology, select-by-location

I'm trying to create a layer from a selection in another layer in ArcMap 10.5.1 like so...

[image]

Doing Right Click Layer - > Selection - > Create Feature from Selected Features after doing my Select by Attributes and Locations. Those are just a Select by Attribute of this `PREFIXDIR = 'W' AND STREETNAME = 'WILLOW' AND STREETSUF = 'ST'` and then select by location all locations like such...

[image]

Then creating the new layer and showing that...

[image]

All is great! But as soon as I try to label the features/symbolize like the previous layer...it brings back all the non-selected features.

Using the following Python expression to label...

[image]

And the symbolology I'm just importing from the previous layer.

As soon as I label or import symbology all the previous features are brought back...

Like for example when I import the symbology

[image]

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in ArcMap according to some [discussion on Esri website.](https://community.esri.com/thread/53023)

A work around is to export the selection as a feature class. Right click the layer -> Data -> Export Data -> Then export selected features using the same coordinate system from this layer's source data.

[image]

Do the symbology and labeling and it works :)

[image]